# Anaconda3-2023.07-1-Linux-ppc64le.sh / Ubuntu 20.04.6 LTS

Tags: command-line

during last step of Anaconda3-2023.07-1-Linux-ppc64le.sh installation
I got message
"Anaconda3-2023.07-1-Linux-ppc64le.sh: line 348: /home/mohamed/anaconda3/conda.exe: cannot execute binary file: Exec format error"

Please advice how to proceed ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`ppc64` is for 64 bit version of PowerPC. Most likely you have a regular 64 bit (amd64) processor.

So, download the amd64 version instead https://repo.anaconda.com/archive/Anaconda3-2023.07-1-Linux-x86_64.sh

Comment: first time after anaconda navigator installation it worked well
later i get this message 
"naconda navigator
usage: anaconda [-h] [--disable-ssl-warnings] [--show-traceback] [-v] [-q]
                [-V] [-t TOKEN] [-s SITE]
                ...
anaconda: error: argument : invalid choice: 'navigator' (choose from 'auth', 'label', 'channel', 'config', 'copy', 'download', 'groups', 'login', 'logout', 'move', 'notebook', 'package', 'remove', 'search', 'show', 'update', 'upload', 'whoami')
tried conda update, conda doctor, conda config --add channel ,,, not successful
any tips ?

Comment: Your comment does not is not properly formatted and is very hard to read. Can you ask a new question?

Comment: I installed anaconda navigator and it worked first time
2nd time, i run again anaconda navigator on Terminal but it doesnt work and I get this message "anaconda navigator usage: anaconda [-h] [--disable-ssl-warnings] [--show-traceback] [-v] [-q] [-V] [-t TOKEN] [-s SITE] ... anaconda: error: argument : invalid choice: 'navigator' (choose from 'auth', 'label', 'channel', 'config', 'copy', 'download', 'groups', 'login', 'logout', 'move', 'notebook', 'package', 'remove', 'search', 'show', 'update', 'upload', 'whoami'
I tried many tricks but not successful.

Comment: problem fixed!!
just old method : remove and reinstall.

Comment: You are supposed to run `conda activate` in terminal, not `anaconda navigator`. See https://www.digitalocean.com/community/tutorials/how-to-install-the-anaconda-python-distribution-on-ubuntu-20-04